# Java Pattern Matching of Tuples

Tags: java, pattern-matching

I have a vector where each object is a tuple containing of types  for ex: <-1,2,3,45.67>. Now i had large set of these tuples, how can i find all the patterns in these tuples, i dont know their start and end points and how many such patterns. 
Need to find all different patterns and how many times they occur?

EX:

> **<1,2,2,68.8752808539275><-1,1,2,68.8752808539275><-1,-2,2,112.60225083387081>**<-2,0,2,158.8752808539275>**<1,2,2,68.8752808539275><-1,1,2,68.8752808539275><-1,-2,2,112.60225083387081>**

Now I need match first three tuples with last tuples as they are identical.
How can I do it in Java?

My input is just a vector of objects, where each object is has the above fields of a class, and i dont give search pattern, it should recognize all different patterns in the vector..

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following:

- First, use a regular expression to geht the actual String, representing ONE tupel. `(<[^>]+>)`
- Create a Tuppel class, that takes that in a constructor, implement the equals and hashcode method as required, and add all results to a set while iterating.

Class:

```
Class MyTupel{
  private int a;
  private int b;
  private int c;
  private double d;

  public MyTupel(String tupel){
    //Regex to match a,b,c,d over here: ^<(\d+),(\d+),(\d+),([^>]+)>$
  }

  public boolean equals(MyTupel another){
    return (a == another.getA() && b == another.getB() && c = another.getC() && d == another.getD())
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode(){
     return a+b+c+ (int)Math.floor(d);
  }

  //getter and setter
}
```

and finally u can use it like (verbal):

- Create List of MyTuppel (or Set)
- foreach Match in String "<1,2,2,68.8752808539275>...."
- Create Tuppel-Instance (`Tuppel t = new Tuppel(match)`)
- if not list contains tuppel: Add tuppel.

Comment: `equals` method is not overriding original `equals` method

Comment: @user902383 You are right. Since i used `MyTuppel` as Parameter it is enough to create a polimorphism. @Override would be necessary, if i used `Object`. But then i need to perform class checks and so on.

Comment: @user902383 Bean counter :) It should not be a copy/paste solution.

Comment: how can i identify first three and last three are same??

Comment: you can simple check `list.contains(tuppel)` - if you already added that, this will return true. (The custom equal function will ignore, that they are different objects. They are rendered equal, when their values are equal)

Answer (score 0):

consider bellowed class

```
class Tuple<A,B,C,D>{

  public Tuple(A a,B b,C c, D d){
 ...
  }

@Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((a == null) ? 0 : a.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((b == null) ? 0 : b.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((c == null) ? 0 : c.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((d == null) ? 0 : d.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Tuple other = (Tuple) obj;
        if (a == null) {
            if (other.a != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!a.equals(other.a))
            return false;
        if (b == null) {
            if (other.b != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!b.equals(other.b))
            return false;
        if (c == null) {
            if (other.c != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!c.equals(other.c))
            return false;
        if (d == null) {
            if (other.d != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!d.equals(other.d))
            return false;
        return true;
 }
}
```